# Jquery Validating grouped multiple select boxes

Tags: jquery, jsfiddle

I am trying to validate multiple multi-select boxes.

There are set of multiple(multi-select) boxes with same name that are grouped with 'sortvalues[]' as name[These are generated by a php code from a mysql table].

Now the task each and every sortvalues[] should have atleast 1 value selected. If a sortvalues box is not selected just alert saying missing value.

Fiddle Link

```
    [http://jsfiddle.net/rvinay/HJ8DK/][1]
```

Awaiting for Your valuble suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('select[name="sortvalues[]"]').each(function () {
    if (!$(this).find("option:selected").length) {
        alert('missing value!');
        return false;
    }
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/HJ8DK/2/)

Answer (score 1):

```
 $.each($("select"), function() {
        if(!$(this).val()) alert('Missing value');
 });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HJ8DK/1/

Or, just one alert:

```
$.each($("select"), function() {
       if(!$(this).val()) { alert('Missing value'); break; }
});
```